# Error in gitlab CI/CD while docker login invalid certificate

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

Hey i got GitLab and gitlab runner runned in docker in gitlab i got working container registry.
when in CI/CD im trying to do

```
stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - build

docker-build:
  # Use the official docker image.
  image: docker:latest
  services:
   - docker:dind
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD | docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER $CI_REGISTRY --password-stdin
```

I got error like
`Get "https://git.domain.com:5050/v2/": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

my runner config.toml looks like this

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "Runner"
  url = "http://git.domain.com/"
  id = 3
  token = "xxxxxxxxxcccccc"
  token_obtained_at = 2023-02-07T22:14:54Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker"
  clone_url = "http://git.domain.com/"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "node:latest"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

What can i do with this?

When i do login from my pc its works perfect

edit:
My cert is not selfsigned

Answer (score 1):

I added my CA certificate to certificate, and now its works